# Is there a way to specify a section of a pipeline be completely "pass through"?

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a script in which data is processed by streaming it through a fairly large pipeline. Several sections of the pipeline are actually "switchboard" functions that do different things based on some external parameter. A contrived example is given below.

```
#! /bin/bash

switchboard() {
    # Select the appropriate command depending on input.
    case "$1" in
        1)
            sort
            ;;
        2)
            awk '{ print $5 }' | sort
            ;;
        *)
            cat  # <= Is there something more optimal here?
            ;;
    esac
}

# The data processing pipeline.
<"$1" tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | switchboard "$2" | head -n 10
```

In the "switchboard" function, the fallback is just to use `cat` to send the input directly to the output. This works just fine, but in my pipeline I may have many "switchboards" and I'd like to avoid creating a bunch of do-nothing `cat` processes if possible.

Is there some sort of bash built-in (or alternative) that can be used to specify that a given section of a pipeline should connect STDOUT directly to STDIN without having to use a subprocess? (I tried `:` but that just ate the data) Or, does `cat` use such a small amount of resources that this is a non-issue?

Comment: ksh implentations (e.g. mksh) have internal builtin cat command which is faster.

Comment: @Fólkvangr The name “switchboard” and the labels are for demonstrative purposes only, hence my calling it a “contrived example”.

Comment: Unless you have thousands of switchboards running simultaneously, a few extra `cat` processes isn't going to affect your performance. Off the top of my head, I can't think of a better way to do it.

Comment: Similar: [Conditional pipeline](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/38310)

Answer (score 1):

First, the use of yet another `cat` doesn't really make much difference, and you shouldn't bother about it.

Second, the commands that make up a pipeline are executed in separate processes anyway, no matter if they're external commands or built-ins:

```
$ a=0
$ a=1 | a=2 | a=3
$ echo $a
0
```

As to your exact problem, it's not possible to simply connect 'stdin' to 'stdout'; even if a shell had some `nop` builtin which would collapse when used in a pipeline (eg `| nop |` -> `|`), the shell has no way to know in advance, at the time it sets up the pipeline, that your "switchboard" will switch to `nop` instead of `awk` or `sort`.

You can also achieve the same effect as you "switchboards" by building the pipeline yourself, and then calling eval to run it. Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
type=`file -zi "$1"`
case $type in
*application/gzip*)     mycat='zcat "$1"';;
*)                      mycat='cat "$1"';;
esac
case $type in
*charset=utf-16le*)     mycat="$mycat | iconv -f utf16le";;
esac
# highlight comments in blue
esc=`printf '\033'`;
mycat="$mycat | sed 's/^#.*/$esc[34m&$esc[m/'"
echo >&2 "$mycat"    # show the built pipeline
eval "$mycat"   # ... and run it
$ iconv -t utf16 test.sh > test16.sh; gzip test16.sh
$ sh test.sh test16.sh.gz
```

That's a bit off-topic, but on linux there is a faster way to copy the stdin to stdout (if any of them is a pipe) -- the `splice(2)` syscall, which doesn't involve moving the data to and from the userland:

```
$ cat splice_cat.c
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <err.h>

int main(int ac, char **av){
    ssize_t r;
    size_t block = ac > 1 ? strtoul(av[1], 0, 0) : 0x20000;
    for(;;)
            if((r = splice(0, NULL, 1, NULL, block, 0)) < 1){
                    if(r < 0) err(1, "splice");
                    return 0;
            }
}
$ cc -Wall splice_cat.c -o splice_cat
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 status=none | (time cat >/dev/null)
real    0m0.153s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.056s
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=100 status=none | (time ./splice_cat >/dev/null)
real    0m0.100s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.020s
```

However (afaik), that's not used by either the shell or `cat`, `dd`, etc.

Comment: You can use `pv -q` to use `splice()`.

Comment: I was initially going to use the string building approach, but then I read somewhere that when shell scripting one should "use strings for text, not for code" so I went with the "switchboard" approach.  Is "use strings for text, not for code" more of a guideline than a rule?

Comment: If you want my opinion, that's more of a cargo-cult mantra than anything. You don't need macros and evals to turn everything into a mess ;-)

Comment: @SethMMorton The approach you detail in your example is arguably easier to audit than the eval approach, and has the nice side effect that it's more modular.  Performance-wise, there should be no difference between the two (the eval method _might_ use a bit more memory, but not much).